# jQuery.on function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and I need to perform an action to a td which is dynamically added. I tried to use jQyuery.on function but my code is not being called. Help please! Here's my code

**HTML**

```
<div>First Name:
    <input type="text" name="txtFName" id="txtFName" />
    <br/>Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="txtLName" id="txtLName" />
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Add User" id="btnAdd" />
</div>
<br/>
<div>Users
    <table id="tblusers">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbUsers"></tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Save Users" />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var content = "";
        var fName = $('#txtFName').val();
        var lName = $('#txtLName').val(); ;
        content = "<tr><td>" + fName + "</td><td>" + lName + "</td><td class=\"clremove\">Delete</td></tr>";
        $('#tbUsers').append(content);
    });

    $('.clremove').on('click', function () {
        $('#tbUsers tr').remove($(this).closest('tr'));
    });
});
```

Here's my [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/jobzky/txKEs/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.clremove` does not exist when you call `.on`, so nothing gets bound.  You want to use event delegation:

```
$("#tbUsers").on('click', '.clremove', function () {
    $("#tbUsers tr").remove($(this).closest('tr'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

since your `clremove` is added dynamically , `$('.clremove').on('click'..` event won't fire (which at a time is not present in the docuemnt).. you can use on() delegated event for this.

```
$('#tbUsers').on('click','.clremove' function () {
    $('#tbUsers tr').remove($(this).closest('tr'));
});
```

you can go  through the [link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) if you want to read more about `jquery.on` and its direct and delegated events.